# How can I write an array of arraylist in the uml?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, uml

This is my array of arraylist: `Arraylist[] a = new Arraylist[SIZE];`

I’m struggling with writing it in my UML diagram, how can I write it?
With or without the <>?

Comment: You should probably state which language you are actually using. And also the occurence of the `<>` is unclear.

Comment: also is *a* really an attribute of a class ? is *SIZE* the size the array will **always** have ?

Comment: Edit your question to answer to the remarks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to define it this way:

[image]

`a` is of type `Arraylist` (after the colon) with multiplicity `0..*` and its default (after the equal sign) is `Arraylist[SIZE]`.

As commented by [@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458991/bruno) the default value is a bit of interpretation. UML basically should be held language agnostic, but sometimes you just want to point out implementation details (for whatever reason). So you can add the `new` keyword right in front of the `Arraylist[SIZE]`. What that actually means is language dependent (and so out of a general scope I like to stick to).

Comment: I am perplex about the removed *new*, because you specify the default value using the (probable) Java form why to truncate it removing the *new*, but at the same time to have it also disturb me.

Comment: I mean : in Java `new Arraylist[SIZE]` creates an array initializing each entry with *null*, so finally `new Arraylist[SIZE]`  only give a size to the array, but for the UML point of view there is no initialization / default value => better to not indicate it ?. Out of that the question is not enough clear => not possible to know if the multiplicity is `*`  or `SIZE`

Comment: @bruno There is no tag about Java being the language. The declaration (in EA) can only be specified with a lower/upper bound. The default is a free text string. I could add the "new" keyword but I think this is something very language specific. UML should be language agnostic.

Comment: The tags includes *arraylist* referring language like Java. But whatever that just allocates an array where the elements are null in case of a language using pointers like Java or with their default value from their constructor (like C++ even not C++) or are non initialized at all. The exact behavior depends on the language so better to put the full form rather than a part of (`Arraylist[SIZE]` is not more or less language agnostic than `new Arraylist[SIZE]` ;-) ), or in fact nothing because just allocate an array.

Comment: @bruno I think I will just annotate the answer with your remark. Like so often there is no right and wrong but something to interprete...

Comment: Having the OP coming back to say the size of the array is always SIZE would be the best, after that `a: Arraylist[SIZE]` and no discussion / interpretation :) Unfortunately even the OP was back 7 hours ago no additional inputs :(

Comment: @bruno He's probably scared/disturbed due to the question being closed.

Comment: it was closed to request details. I let OP more than enough time to allow to answer to remarks, without more from OP I asked to close